# $_Get and &_REQUEST Index Undefined on Functions.php

Tags: functions, theme-options

I recently try to learn create a theme options page for my custom theme, is follow the tutorial from stackoverflow and other resource. but the script show an error

```
if ($_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__)) {
    if ('save' == $_REQUEST['formaction']) {
        foreach ($options as $value) {
            if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) {
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  );
            }
            else {
                delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }
        }

        foreach ($spawned_options as $value) {
            if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) {
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  );
            }
            else {
                delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }
        }
        header("Location: themes.php?page=options.php&saved=true");
        die;
    }
    else if('reset_all' == $_REQUEST['formaction']) {
        foreach ($options as $value) {
            delete_option( $value['id'] );
        }

        foreach ($spawned_options as $value) {
            delete_option( $value['id'] );
        }
        header("Location: themes.php?page=options.php&".$_REQUEST['formaction']."=true");
        die;
    }
```

}

I got error on this line

```
if ($_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__)) {
    if ('save' == $_REQUEST['formaction']) {
```

The error message say "Notice: Undefined index: page ....." and "Notice: Undefined index: formaction ...."

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel!!!!!!!! either integrate with the cutomize4r or use the settings API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if those values actually exist first.

You can use `isset()` for this. By adding something similar to the follow at the top of your function.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['page'], $_REQUEST['formaction'] ) ) {
    return;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: I have fixed it after add isset on the script. But i've got a error message on my text input area..

<br /><b>Notice</b>:  get_settings is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 2.1.0! Use get_option() instead. in <b>/home/wendy93/public_html/domain_addon/ericliputra.com/wp-includes/functions.php</b> on line <b>3839</b><br />

Comment: I think that error is pretty self explanatory. However if you still need help with it you should make a new question. If I have answered your first correctly please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: just found the error.. I used a old script that use get_settings(), which is since version 2.1.0 the get_settings is changed to get_option().. LMAO.. So, i just changed it from get_settings() to get_option to fix the issue.. Thanks for your time and reply.. Hehe